# Recursively test for connection with RMySQL until successful

Tags: r, recursion, rmysql

I am writing a script that has to run on its own (a cron job), and need to connect to a MySQL database and perform some operations. I am using the package RMySQL in order to do so.

Since it has to be run automatically, I'd like the script to recursively test whether the connection was successful via checking if there are actually any tables in the connection. So far, with no luck I have tried the following:

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="test")
FCSQL <- function(connection) {
  if (length(dbListTables(connection)) == 0 ) {
  con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="test")
  connection <- FCSQL(connection)
 FCSQL(connection)
  } else {
  return("ON")
  }
}

FCSQL(con)
#the error for the previous example:
#Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
#connection with pending rows, close resultSet before continuing
```

A slight modification with the same error:

```
FCSQL <- function(connection) {
  if (length(dbListTables(connection)) == 0 ) {
  con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="test")
  FCSQL(con)
  } else {
  return("ON")
  }
 }

 FCSQL(con)
 #Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
 #connection with pending rows, close resultSet before continuing
```

Comment: Try closing `connection` before starting a new one to the same host.